# How to solve "Could not install the full language support in Ubuntu 20.04 " and install Hindi and Tamil languages?

Tags: package-management, system-installation, system-settings, input-language, language-support

I got an error image like this:

[image: Language Installation Error]

How do I install Hindi and Tamil languages? Are there any other steps to install these languages in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Looks like a problem with LibreOffice. Maybe a reinstall of the common package will clear things up. Run this in a terminal: `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice-common`

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-common`? Please run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and share full error output to pastebin.